# Error: XML document expecting opening tag after final closing tag

Tags: xml

I'm getting an xml error, and I'm aware similar questions exist elsewhere, yet there's no answer for my situation. I've run xmllint telling me that a starting tag is expected...at the end of the document. All my tags are closed as far as I'm aware, so I'm not sure why it's expecting what it's expecting...

'''

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href=/Users/Andrew/Desktop/schoolwork/devicexsl.xsl>
<device>
    <phone>
        <make> Apple </make>
        <model> iPhone 12 </model>
        <OS> iOS </OS>
        <osVersion>14.4</osVersion>
        <color> Blue </color>
        <screensize> 6.1 </screensize>
        <price>€914 </price>
    </phone>
    <tablet>
        <make> Apple </make>
        <model> iPad Air </model>
        <OS> iOS </OS>
        <osVersion> 14.1 </osVersion>
        <color> Black </color>
        <screensize> 11 </screensize>
        <price> €700 </price>
    </tablet>
</device>
```

'''

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the **exact** error message you received. There may be details in there that you don't understand, but which someone else can explain to you.

Comment: the Terminal says "Error on line 22 column 10 of device.xml:
  SXXP0003   Error reported by XML parser: XML document structures must start and end within
  the same entity.: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/Users/andreweckerberg/Desktop/schoolwork/TRANSFORMATIONS/device.xml; lineNumber: 22; columnNumber: 10; XML document structures must start and end within the same entity."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single question mark was missing at the end of the 2nd line.

Here is your well-formed XML.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href=/Users/Andrew/Desktop/schoolwork/devicexsl.xsl?>
<device>
    <phone>
        <make>Apple</make>
        <model>iPhone 12</model>
        <OS>iOS</OS>
        <osVersion>14.4</osVersion>
        <color>Blue</color>
        <screensize>6.1</screensize>
        <price>€914</price>
    </phone>
    <tablet>
        <make>Apple</make>
        <model>iPad Air</model>
        <OS>iOS</OS>
        <osVersion>14.1</osVersion>
        <color>Black</color>
        <screensize>11</screensize>
        <price>€700</price>
    </tablet>
</device>
```

Comment: oh my god are you kidding me?! lol thank you, it was actually wrecking my head 